# NetworkX package using dataframe with weights labeled

Tags: python, networkx

I have a portion of dataframe as below (`con_df`):

```
from  to    fw
1     2    no fw
1     4    fw
2     3    no fw
2     5    no fw
2     6    no fw
2     7    fw
```

with 3 variables

want to make a graph using NetworkX

```
network = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df=con_df, source='from', target='to',
                                  edge_attr='fw', create_using=nx.MultiGraph())
nx.draw(network, with_labels = True)
```

above is the code i used, the output is below,
the problem is that the weight option is not shown on the graph.
i thought that the edge_attr option is for the weight attribute, but it does not work

what i want is the fw variable is being labeled in the edge of the graph

is there a problem in the code or should i approach in different way?

[image]

Comment: what would you expect here?

Comment: sorry for confusion i have edited the question. what i want is the fw variable is being labeled in the edge of the graph as "fw", "no fw"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with_labels` refers to the **nodes** labels, not that of the edges.

You need to use [`nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html):

```
labels = {x[:2]: network.get_edge_data(*x)['fw']  for x in network.edges}
pos = nx.spring_layout(network)
nx.draw(network, pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(network, pos, edge_labels=labels)
```

output:

[image: networkx MultiGraph with edges labels]

content of the `labels` dictionary:

```
{(1, 2): 'no fw',
 (1, 4): 'fw',
 (2, 3): 'no fw',
 (2, 5): 'no fw',
 (2, 6): 'no fw',
 (2, 7): 'fw'}
```